# MIPS Error in : invalid program counter value: 0x00000000

Tags: stack, mips

```
test_1:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $ra,  0($sp)

    jal test_2

    lw $ra,  0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra

test_2:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $ra,  4($sp)

    jal test_3

    lw $ra,  4($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra
```

Error: `Error in : invalid program counter value: 0x00000000. Go: execution terminated with errors.`

I don't understand why I get this error. My understanding is that `test_1` makes space for one in the stack and saves its `$ra`. After the `jal test_2` instruction we jump to `test_2` and here `test_2` makes space  for the second `$ra` (-4 -4 = -8).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The logic for saving and restoring should be the same in both subroutines, so I find your code a bit strange.

Comment: 1. You haven't posted a _complete_ minimal example that can be used to reproduce the issue. 2. By the looks of it, `test_2` overwrites the value stored on the stack by `test_1`, because it for some reason uses an offset of 4.